# Realvnc has two sessions listed for 1 user to connect to. How do I merge them?

Tags: vnc

[image]

It's the same user(pi), same pi. But different desktops when I log in (see left and right). I just want one raspberry pi session for simplicity and am interested in how I even managed to create two sessions.

Comment: We can only guess what you did, but I see no problem - you can have multiple sessions. just close the one you don't want.

Comment: @Milliways I guess I wanted to know really what's going on. How can the same user login twice. Maybe a better  question for unix stack exchange

Comment: A user can login multiple times - this is normal operation. Normally with RealVNC they would see the same desktop, but you can create as many Virtual Desktops as you like. Unless you say WHAT YOU DID we can only guess.

Comment: @Milliways ah, ok,. the keyword virtual desktops and google should get me the explanation I need. thanks.

Comment: You have 2 VNC server running: the one on the left is virtual mode (you can tell by the :1 in the title bar), which you would have started via the vncserver or vncserver-virtual command. The one on the right is the service mode server, which is showing you the actual display output that you would see on a monitor, which you would have started via raspi-config or systemctl.